# changing title in multiplot ggplot2 using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have managed to make a 2x2 plot using grid.arrange:

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p3,p2,p4, ncol=2, nrow=2, top = "Daily QC: Blue")
```

The main title of this multiplot is very small. Is there a way to change the title text size and font.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
main=textGrob("Daily QC: Blue",gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=3))
```

*Edit* with v>=2.0.0 of gridExtra, `main` has become `top` (for consistency with `bottom`, `left` and `right`).

Answer (score 57):

Due to changes in both packages `grid` and `gridExtra`, the current answer is outdated. Library package `grid` is also required to use `textGrob` and `gpar`.

The new code should include both packages:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1,p3,p2,p4, ncol=2, nrow=2,
     top = textGrob("Daily QC: Blue",gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=3)))
```