# changing multiple line title in multiplot ggplot2 using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have followed the advice on the discussion

[changing title in multiplot ggplot2 using grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726078/changing-title-in-multiplot-ggplot2-using-grid-arrange)

but my 2-line title doesn't change the font size.

1- should I state main in grid.arrange or do I use grid.arrange without main and then, add the following script

```
main=textGrob(paste("titleLine1", "titleLine2", sep = "\n"),gp=gpar(fontsize=20))
```

Thanks

Carol

Comment: yes, it works. I had used them separately grid.arrange in one line and textGrob on the 2nd line.

Comment: What should be done if I want to display title1 one the 1st row with for ex fontsize = 18 and title2 on the 2nd row with  fontsize = 16?

Comment: note that with v>=2.0.0 of gridExtra the `main` argument has been renamed `top`

Answer (score 9):

Here's one possibility,

[image]

```
library(grid); library(gridExtra)
tg <- textGrob("Title Goes Here", gp=gpar(fontsize=30))
sg <- textGrob("more subtle subtitle ", gp=gpar(fontsize=15, fontface=3L))
margin <- unit(0.5, "line")
grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(tg, sg, rectGrob(), 
             heights = unit.c(grobHeight(tg) + 1.2*margin, 
                              grobHeight(sg) + margin, 
                              unit(1,"null")))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could go in a different direction and use **ggplot2** latest build from `github`:

```
library(ggplot2) # (github version) devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")

p <-  ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist))
p <- p + theme_bw()
p <- p + geom_bar(fill="blue", stat="identity")
p <- p + labs(title="Fast Cars",
              subtitle="Are more Fun")
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=0, vjust=1)) 
p <- p + theme(plot.title=element_text(size=30, hjust=0.5, face="bold", colour="darkgreen", vjust=-1))
p <- p + theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(size=20, hjust=0.5, face="italic", color="darkred"))
p
```

This was added pretty recently here:
https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1582

let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

The paste command provides newline separation that currently (December 2015) is correctly interpreted by gridExtra:

```
heres_the_tricky_part <- paste("mainTitle", "subTitle", sep="\n")

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, nrow=1, ncol=2, top=heres_the_tricky_part )
```