# Avoiding font changes when exporting grid.arrange plot to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am using the grid.arrange function to arrange a set of 4 plots and add a title to them.
I would like to export the result as a pdf but whenever I do so, the font of the title (although not the font used in the plots themselves) changes.
Is there some way to avoid this? The code is as follows

```
grid.arrange(
  eeplot,
  ueplot,
  euplot,
  uuplot,
  nrow = 2,
  top=textGrob("Worker Households", gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=6))
)
```

In the viewer everything looks fine

[image]

but when I export the plot to pdf the result is this

[image]

As can be seen, the font of the title (but not that of the tick labels of the plots themselves) has changed.

EDIT: When I export individual plots made in ggplot2 to pdf, I do not run into this issue. It only occurs when using grid.arrange

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you would consider making this a reproducible example, e.g. creating plots with an inbuilt data set, you are much more likely to get help

Comment: gridextra likely has different defaults for devices. this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726078/changing-title-in-multiplot-ggplot2-using-grid-arrange/14726338   or use the `patchwork` package instead

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that there is a simple fix to this.

Replacing

```
top=textGrob("Worker Households", gp=gpar(fontsize=20,font=6))
```

with

```
top=textGrob("Worker Households", gp=gpar(fontsize=20,fontfamily="serif"))
```

solves the issue.