# Page titles for multi-page PDF using marrangeGrob and ggsave in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am using `marrangeGrob` and `ggsave` to export a series of graphs. When I output the sample code below, it gives page numbers (e.g., 1 of 6, 2 of 6, ...) at the top of the page. I know this can easily be removed with `top = NULL`. But I would like to change the title for each page either from the list of plot objects (which are named) or from a character vector (e.g., `plot_names` below).

I know I can use other functions like `textGrob` along with `gpar` to change the title, font, size of font, etc. (e.g., [changing title in multiplot ggplot2 using grid.arrange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726078/changing-title-in-multiplot-ggplot2-using-grid-arrange)).  But I have not found a straightforward way to change the title on each page.

**Sample Data**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Create some plots
p1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = cyl)
p2 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars) + ggtitle("title")
p3 <- qplot(mpg, data = mtcars, geom = "dotplot")
plots <- list(p1, p2, p3)
plot_names <- c("A_Plot_1", "A_Plot_2", "B_Plot_1")
names(plots) <- plot_names


# Combine into a list, and change where page numbers will appear
Export <- gridExtra::marrangeGrob(plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

# Export to a pdf file
ggsave(filename = "multipage.plots.pdf", Export, scale = 1.5)
```

Also, notice that these are not necessarily just sequential plots (e.g., A_Plot, B_Plot, etc.).

**Expected Output**

Here is what I would like for the PDFs to look like.

[image: A_Plot_1 on page 1 of pdf]

[image: A_Plot_2 on page 2 of pdf]

[image: B_Plot_1 on page 3 of pdf]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `top` parameter to something you want. The default value is

```
top = quote(paste("page", g, "of", npages))
```

So you can pass a quoted expression that will be evaulated for each plot where `g` is the current plot index and `npages` is the total number of plots. So in your case, you can extract the values from your vector

```
Export <- gridExtra::marrangeGrob(plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 1,
                                  top=quote(names(plots)[g]))
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much! I knew there had to be simple way to do it. I was just missing the `[g]` when I tried to use `quote` before. It also looks like if you don't have a named list (i.e., if `names(plots) <- plot_names` was omitted above), then you could just pass a character vector to get the same result. `Export <- gridExtra::marrangeGrob(plots, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, top=quote(plot_names[g]))`